# Codenameone, How can i bind a value to the MultiButton item without displaying it on UI

Tags: codenameone

I am creating a Multibutton from an ArrayList, There is two keys involved. "id" and "code". I only want to display "code" on the UI and hide "id" because i only need "id" for the actionListener.

**My approach**, open for correction

I only want to show TextLine1 ["code"] and hide TextLine2 ["id"]

```
for(int x= 0; x < policies2.size(); x++)
{
  final MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();   
  Double policy_id = (Double)policies2.get(x).get("id");
  mb.setTextLine1((String) policies2.get(x).get("code"));
  mb.setTextLine2(policies2.get(x).get("policy_id")+""); //how can i hide this/bind it to the Multi withou showing it on the UI.
  mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   //use "id" here
   //mb.getTextLine2()
 }
}
```

How can i use "id" without showing it on the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();   
  final Double policy_id = (Double)policies2.get(x).get("id");
  mb.setTextLine1((String) policies2.get(x).get("code"));
  //mb.setTextLine2(policies2.get(x).get("policy_id")+""); //how can i hide this/bind it to the Multi withou showing it on the UI.
  mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actiobPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      double id = policy_id.doubleValue();
      ...
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I solved it please check my answer, its actually same approach. I was just 1 minute earlier than u :)

Comment: it's similar to what I did although I am not familiar with the details of your specific code. There is no need to bind it to the MultiButton just mark it has final and access it in the actionPerformed clause

Answer (score 1):

This was quite simple actually.
I just declared the id outside addActionListener inner class as final, I didn't have to set it to TextLine2.

```
final Double db = (Double)policies2.get(x).get("policy_id");
mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  System.out.println(db);
}
```